# How to get doxygen to use C# naming formats?

Tags: doxygen

My project is in C# and I'm generating some docs using doxygen. I set the INPUT option to point to the directory where all my *.cs source files are. Everything is mostly fine. But when the classes.html index page is generated, some class names (specifically inner classes and enums) appear C++ style. For example:

ClassName::EnumValue

whereas it should be

ClassName.EnumValue

Any way to fix this?